# use of image maps in jQuery Mobile/HTML5

Tags: image, jquery-mobile

I want to use [image maps](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/map.html) & http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-map-element.html#dom-map-images. I haven't seen much of this kind of usage(exception might be in case of HTML5 Canvas because one of the above link is of HTML5, not sure though) and since advent of jquery and other libraries. I guess there are more easier ways to implement this. So I was wondering if there are any libraries or better ways to implement image maps in jQuery Mobile or do I need to go with the old practice.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge image maps are not introduced in HTML5, but there are supported in all browser since many years.

I am not sure, what you want to achieve with jquery library, but I have used couple of years ago for highlighting image map areas,& it worked like a charm.

maphighlight: 
http://davidlynch.org/blog/2008/03/maphilight-image-map-mouseover-highlighting/
Demo:
http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_world.html

Comment: Thanks, I am also looking if there are any alternatives for using in jQuery Mobile or just using the ususal Javascript code only